# How can I start porting Ubuntu Touch to the iPhone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, iphone, smartphone, porting

I've been interested in porting Ubuntu to my Apple hardware for quite some time and I'm coming to the conclusion that I'm going to have to do the port myself but I have no idea how to complete such a task.

Please advise me on how to port an OS to another device, steps involved, and what I need to teach myself to be successful. Don't tell me Apple wont allow it, its my hardware outright and I'm dissatisfied with the current operating system on my hardware.

The phone was purchased for full price, and I completed a 2 year contract agreement, and the iPhone hasn't been used as a phone for a couple of years now. I've seen Android on the iPhone so my assumption is that it is possible.

Thanks for your replies in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, you probably can't do this on your own.

That being said, Ubuntu Touch, IIRC, is based in part on Android. So you'd need to take or make a build of Android that runs on iPhone and port Ubuntu Touch to it using [these instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting).

Comment: Here's a head start: http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/IDroid     Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There was an attempt to get android to run on iOS devices called [iDroid](http://www.idroidproject.org/). The project is officially dead and I have tried numerous times to contact the original dev to see if he had plans on trying again but to no avail.

They do have a [GitHub for the last attempt at it](https://github.com/iDroid-Project/openiBoot) but that is only the first step. You would then need something like cyanogenmod (I think is the name) to be able to run on your mock iDroid before attempting to get ubuntu touch to load on your already over stressed device.

I wish I knew more to help out because I would love to see this come to fruition. But this is all I can provide. Wonder if ubuntu has thought to try and hack iOS to run it for jailbroken devices.